# Ни... ни. Запятая

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

*До полуночи Артем, словно в дреме, **ни** веселый **(,)** **ни** грустный, развозил клиентов.*

Можно ли здесь говорить о тесном смысловом единстве членов предложения, связанных союзом "ни"? Или, раз это не устойчивое выражение, нужно обязательно ставить перед вторым "ни" запятую?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*До полуночи Артем, **словно в дреме, ни веселый, ни грустный**, развозил клиентов.*

Здесь авторский выбор: вы можете обозначать или не обозначать тесную связь антонимических слов.

Обособленный составной оборот "словно в дрЕме, ни весЕлый, ни грУстный" интонационно лучше читается при постановке ударения **на каждом слове**.

При объединении прилагательных они имеют **одно ударение**: До полуночи Артем, словно в дрЕме, ни веселый ни грУстный, развозил клиентов.

Но в принципе этот вопрос решается самим автором.